# Chrome printing 2 table in different page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have 2 tables in a html page.

I am trying to print the html page.

But when opening the popup. Two tables are showing in two different pages.

Before some time it used to print 2 table in a single page (if proper space is available).

But from some time now it is showing 2 tables in two different pages.

I have tried adding `page-break-after: avoid` but still it is print in different page.

What should I do??

Following is the 2 tables showing in 2 pages.

But it was supposed to print both table in same page since there is proper space is available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using **Chrome 108** on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `page-break-after: avoid;` for the tfoot and it seemed to solve the problem.

```css
tfoot {
    page-break-after: avoid !important;
}
```